# How obtain the Distance/Proximity between 2 fields?

Tags: 7, views, location

I am working on a project ([Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega) subtheme) with [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). I'm trying to create a list of local secondary schools and their distance from a few locations.

Installed Location Module, enabled it, together with Location Search, Location Taxonomy, Node Locations and Location CCK. Also, imported list of zipcodes for my location (gb) into database.

Next I created Content Type ‘secodnary school’ with School Location field, containing Address ,Postal Code, City, Country, and Latitude and Longitude fields.

Then I created 3 pieces of content – namely 3 local schools (to start with) with their addresses and lat/long info.

Finally, I tried to create a view that will contain the above list of secondary schools, sorted by their proximity to the given location and to connect it to a different piece of content (page) that holds the location info (address, postcode, latitude/longitude) of different (X,Y,Z) locations.
X, Y, Z (…) are pieces of content (pages) of XYZ content type that among other things contain their individual location info.

So I need my new view (lets call it distance_sec_schools) to pick up location info from it’s host (XYZ) content  (hint: I tried to configure CONTEXTUAL FILTER – content NID to provide content ID from URL – but it didn’t do the trick) and then provide me with the distances to 3 local schools, which I will then sort by proximity criteria.

Take a look at the screenshots of my view and Location: Distance / Proximity - Field Settings (framed red) and Filter (framed blude), which I suspect might be where my problem lies.

At the moment, my view produces a table with the school names but without the distances.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not built into the location module but can easily be done in php with Haversine Formula, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053358/measuring-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php).

To add it to your view you can use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) or theme a field with views-view-field--your-field.tpl.php passing in the two coordinates.